# Preg_match in php not working properly when i tried it

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get it to echo "match", but it keep echoing "not match". What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$string = "anyway, why is it not matching?";
if (preg_match("~^([a-z]+ |[,.!?] ?)?(who|whom|what|where|when|why|how|which)[s]?\b~i", $string)) {
echo "match";
}
else { echo "not match"; }

?>
```

Comment: `[a-z]+ |[,.!?] ?)` these space, must be in the match, and this `[s]` matches `s` none or one time `?`, which is probably not what you want because `[...]` is generally a set of characters, not a single one.  And you could do the same thing with `s?`, it's generally better to use `\b` around words because it matches anything not `\w`  (or matches `\W` however you want to say it)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix So what is the right preg_match?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to "match"  or do as you give no examples of that.  (and I have other things to do besides Stack Overflow, so I'm off for the night)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I'm trying to match, starts with either a single word or punctuation. if it's a punctuation then a space may or may not follow it. And then after that just matches (why)

Comment: because, there may be better ways to do this then try to blind fix something,  for example the `[s]?` doesn't make a lot of sense,  for example it would match only `whos,whoms,whats,wheres,whens,whys,hows,whichs` and again it makes little sense to have it in a character group `[]` but it's optional  `?` so it's largely going to get ignored.  But I doubt its put there for no reason.  So, when it comes to Regex the context really matters otherwise there is no way to "logically" know why that was put there.  Also logically optional matches at the end that don't end a string `$` can be omitted

Comment: Its like saying match `this` and end that match with this thing or ... muah end it without out.  In otherwords it doesn't matter to the match at all, even if there was a reason to match `whoms` because you still have the `whom` match

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52940344/edit) and add test cases Some string that must match and some other.

Answer (score 1):

The start of your regex `^([a-z]+ |[,.!?] ?)` denotes that the string must start with any number of letters followed by a space, or exactly one punctuation mark followed by a space.

What you want is to match one to one words followed by zero to one punctuation characters followed by zero to one spaces:

```
^([a-z]+[,.!?]? ?)?
~^([a-z]+[,.!?]? ?)?(who|whom|what|where|when|why|how|which)[s]?\b~i
```

This will match the comma and space in the first group, and `why` in the second group, as can be seen broken ndown on Regexer **[here](https://regex101.com/r/1POHH3/1/)** and working on 3v4l **[here](https://3v4l.org/L2OtS)**.

Comment: But sometimes there aren't [,.!?] and that's when it doesn't match.

Comment: So update your data set to match zero or one of those characters with the  quantifier `?` (as `[,.!?]?`).  I've updated my answer to showcase that.